# Adding a Logo to the Eagle Board file

Tags: eaglecad

There are instructions out there on the web on how to import a Bitmap file into Eagle CAD and it's an option in the "File" menu so it should not be a problem. I'm going through the process and finding that at no point does Eagle prompt me for the actual bitmap file that I want to import. It goes through the steps of selecting colours and gives me the Eagle CAD Logo. It's a great Logo but not the one I want to use on my boards.

I'm still on eagle 6.5.0 so maybe there's a problem on that version?

Comment: There's no problem with your Eagle version; There was an .ULP script in the installation directory. I forgot what it was called. bmp2brd.ulp, or something in that manner.

Comment: I followed this instructable: http://www.instructables.com/id/Adding-Custom-Graphics-to-EAGLE-PCB-Layouts/

Comment: I went back to those instructions on Instructables.com but on the second page of the instructions where the User is prompted for the .bmp file I'm not getting that at all. I go straight to colour selection.

Comment: I've tried a few ulp files but as an example I've used import-bmp-scale.bmp

Comment: Araghhhh. Got it! Sorry when I used "File -> Import BMP" I was getting prompted for the bmp file I thought it was asking me to select the ulp file. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: jwhitmore, you are encouraged to add the solution as an answer: that is great if somebody have the same problem!

Comment: A problem you may or not run into with your board house is that they use what is essentially a low dpi printer for that mask. If you import at a dpi that is too high (much over 300) then your image may or may not show up.